# Designing a layout in SAPUI5

Tags: layout, responsive-design, sapui5

I'm designing a layout in SAPUI5, but I'm having trouble in picking the best fitting layout for the job. I have tried a [Grid Layout](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.Grid) and a [Simple Form](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm), but I can't seem to get them right. There's always some scalability issues etc. If anyone would point me in the right direction to create such a layout, that would be a really good start for me. Any tips or suggestions will be massively appreciated.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

**Desktop**
[image]

**Mobile**
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope this will help you, using the *Grid layout* and layout `GridData` properties you can achieve it.

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  controllerName="example.responsiveDesign">
  <Page
    title="Title">
    <content>
      <l:VerticalLayout
        width="100%">
        <l:Grid
          containerQuery="true"
          hSpacing="1"
          vSpacing="1"
          position="Center">
          <Input
            type="Text">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL4 L4 M4 S8" />
            </layoutData>
          </Input>
          <Button
            text="Default"
            width="100%">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL2 L2 M2 S4" />
            </layoutData>
          </Button>
          <Input
            type="Text">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL4 L4 M4 S8" />
            </layoutData>
          </Input>
          <Button
            text="Default"
            width="100%">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL2 L2 M2 S4" />
            </layoutData>
          </Button>
          <Input
            type="Text">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL4 L4 M4 S8" />
            </layoutData>
          </Input>
          <Button
            text="Default"
            width="100%">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL2 L2 M2 S4" />
            </layoutData>
          </Button>
          <Input
            type="Text">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL4 L4 M4 S8" />
            </layoutData>
          </Input>
          <Button
            text="Default"
            width="100%">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL2 L2 M2 S4" />
            </layoutData>
          </Button>
          <Input
            type="Text">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL12 L12 M12 S12" />
            </layoutData>
          </Input>
          <Input
            type="Text">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL6 L6 M6 S12" />
            </layoutData>
          </Input>
          <Input
            type="Text">
            <layoutData>
              <l:GridData
                span="XL6 L6 M6 S12" />
            </layoutData>
          </Input>
        </l:Grid>
      </l:VerticalLayout>
    </content>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

#### Desktop

[image]

#### Mobile

[image]

Note: Include `xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the Grid layout. I designed a small prototype with the layout you're looking for:

```
<mvc:View
       xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
       xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout"
       xmlns="sap.m"
       controllerName="sap.ui.layout.sample.GridProperties.GridProperties"
       xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<layout:VerticalLayout
            width="100%">

 <layout:Grid defaultIndent="L0 M0 S0" defaultSpan="L12 M6 S12" position="Center" width="80%" containerQuery="false" hSpacing="1" vSpacing="1" visible="true">
                <layout:content>
                    <layout:Grid defaultIndent="L0 M0 S0" defaultSpan="L3 M6 S6" position="Center" width="100%" containerQuery="false" hSpacing="0" vSpacing="1" visible="true">
                        <layout:content>
                            <Input type="Text" showValueHelp="false" enabled="true" visible="true" width="100%" valueHelpOnly="false" maxLength="0"/>
                            <Button text="Button" type="Default" iconFirst="true" width="100%" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false"/>
                            <Input type="Text" showValueHelp="false" enabled="true" visible="true" width="100%" valueHelpOnly="false" maxLength="0"/>
                            <Button text="Button" type="Default" iconFirst="true" width="100%" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false"/>
                            <Input type="Text" showValueHelp="false" enabled="true" visible="true" width="100%" valueHelpOnly="false" maxLength="0"/>
                            <Button text="Button" type="Default" iconFirst="true" width="100%" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false"/>
                            <Input type="Text" showValueHelp="false" enabled="true" visible="true" width="100%" valueHelpOnly="false" maxLength="0"/>
                            <Button text="Button" type="Default" iconFirst="true" width="100%" enabled="true" visible="true" iconDensityAware="false"/>
                        </layout:content>
                    </layout:Grid>
                    <Input type="Text" showValueHelp="false" enabled="true" visible="true" width="100%" valueHelpOnly="false" maxLength="0"/>
                    <layout:Grid defaultIndent="L0 M0 S0" defaultSpan="L6 M12 S12" position="Center" width="100%" containerQuery="false" hSpacing="0" vSpacing="1" visible="true">
                        <layout:content>
                            <Input type="Text" showValueHelp="false" enabled="true" visible="true" width="100%" valueHelpOnly="false" maxLength="0"/>
                            <Input type="Text" showValueHelp="false" enabled="true" visible="true" width="100%" valueHelpOnly="false" maxLength="0"/>
                        </layout:content>
                    </layout:Grid>
                </layout:content>
            </layout:Grid>

</layout:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

It's a minimalistic design so it uses no margins or formatting but it should be enough for what you want.

Desktop

[image: Desktop]

Mobile

[image: Mobile]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The button are rather large and when I add a certain width. The spaces become too large... Any idea's I could add?

Comment: <button class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" /> could help